# My Data Only Show One But The Data Should Be More Than One

Tags: sql, vb.net

I have problem with displaying my data. Not all data is displaying. When the name is clicked the data of the person will show. But the problem here is the data is only show one but in fact in the database the data for that person has more than one. Can anyone help me how to display all the data ?

My database table

```
LanguageID    TechnicalProfile_ID    LanguageName    SpokenLevel   WrittenLevel
1              15                   English         10             10
2              15                   Mandarin        5              5
3              15                   Spanish         3              2
4              16                   English         10             9
5              17                   Tamil           10             10
6              17                   Tagalog         10             10
```

The output of my system when clicked Technical Profile ID 15, it only show one data of the Technical Profile ID instead of chowing 3 data. How can I fix this?

Output

```
Language      SpokenLevel     WrittenLevel

Spanish        3               2
```

The output that I want shouls be like below:

```
Language      SpokenLevel     WrittenLevel

English       10              10
Mandarin      5               5
Spanish        3               2
```

My code is as below :

ASPX

```xml
<div class="card-body">
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" >
       <ContentTemplate>
          <asp:CheckBoxList class="list-group-item" ID="chkResourceName1" runat="server" AutoPostBack ="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged ="ResourceName_Click"></asp:CheckBoxList>
       </ContentTemplate>
       <Triggers>
          <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="chkResourceName1"/>
       </Triggers>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</div>
<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="language">
  <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel15" runat="server">
      <ContentTemplate>
         <div class="form-horizontal" role="form">
           <div class="form-group">
             <div class="col-sm-4">
               <b>Language</b>
             </div>
             <div class="col-sm-2">
                <b>Written</b>
             </div>
             <div class="col-sm-2">
               <b>Spoken</b>
             </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="col-sm-4">
                <asp:Label  ID="lblLanguageName" runat="server"></asp:Label>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-2">
                <asp:Label  ID="lblLanguageWritten" runat="server"></asp:Label>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-2">
                <asp:Label   ID="lblLanguageSpoken" runat="server"></asp:Label>
              </div>
            </div>
         </div>
     </ContentTemplate>
  </asp:UpdatePanel>
</div>
```

ASPX code

```vb
Sub ResourceName_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Try 
      Dim LanguageName As String = vbNullString
      Dim WrittenRate As String = vbNullString
      Dim SpokenRate As String = vbNullString

      'To clear result
      lblLanguageName.Text = ""
      lblLanguageWritten.Text = ""
      lblLanguageSpoken.Text = ""

      attPage.SQLQuery = DC.Data_TechnicalResource("12", chkResourceName1.SelectedValue)
      DS = DA.GetSQLDataset(attPage.SQLQuery)
      If DS IsNot Nothing AndAlso DS.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0 Then
         lblLanguageName.Text = DS.Tables(0).Rows(0)("LanguageName").ToString
         lblLanguageWritten.Text = DS.Tables(0).Rows(0)("WrittenLevel").ToString
         lblLanguageSpoken.Text = DS.Tables(0).Rows(0)("SpokenLevel").ToString

      End If
    End Try
End Sub
```

SQL QUERY

```sql
BEGIN
    SELECT *
    From tblLanguage
    where TechnicalProfile_ID = @Parameter1

END
```

Comment: Your code only pulls the data from the first row of the results. How did you expect it to show the other two rows?

Comment: @CaiusJard How can I fix the code ?

Comment: You should iterate through the Dataset and get all the values you want. You should use that IF statement inside a loop that iterates through the number of rows of Dataset

Comment: Can you show me how to do the code @venkat ?

Answer (score 0):

```
If DS IsNot Nothing AndAlso DS.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0 Then
dim dr as datarow
for each dr in DS.tables(0).rows
lblLanguageName.Text = dr("LanguageName").ToString
lblLanguageWritten.Text = dr("WrittenLevel").ToString
lblLanguageSpoken.Text = dr("SpokenLevel").ToString
Next
```

This is how for loop will work, but the **lbLanguageName** is not inside a table, I think the last value will only be printed. Use proper table inorder to load all the values.

Comment: But the lblLanguageName is the the label that I want to show all the data